# Are there any major programming languages that have subtypes like Ada?

Tags: programming-languages, ada

I am getting a little in to c++/qt programming and used to program with Ada at university. One thing I really miss are the subtypes you can create in Ada.
For example you would subtype integer to currency and to weight. And Ada would make sure that you wouldn't assign currency variables to weight variables. Both are basically integers with all functionality intact. You just can't assign them. Is there something like this in any major language? I really miss this.

An example in C++ would be much appreciated. Super complex class constructions and template tinkering does not count :).

Comment: Are you asking about enumerated types?  Or do you have something different in mind?

Comment: Subclassing just for the sake of subclassing doesn't make sense IMO. However, I might be wrong. I have a very limited mindset (according to most people here at Stackoverflow).

Comment: Enumerated types have to be explicitly defined afaik. Ada allows you to have the complete integer range or lets you define a custom range like 1..1024. It is much easier this way.

Comment: Just to nitpick: Ada subtypes (`subtype Foo is Integer range 1 .. 1024`) retain the assignability of the parent type, and can interoperate with other subtypes of the same base type, whereas derived types (type Bar is new Integer range 1 .. 1024`) don't. More in the [Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System#Defining_new_types_and_subtypes).

Comment: well, Ada definitely counts as a major language, so ... yes. It's probably the most popular language with a good range of subtype facilities. You could look at some varieties of Pascal, or VHDL for hardware design, for others.

Comment: I don't see why this question was closed. Imho either there is such a feature in other languages or there isn't. No debate, arguments or extended discussions necessary.

Comment: @problemofficer - It was probably closed due to the wording/phrasing... I'll edit it later today (after church) and we'll see about getting it reopened.

Comment: In Java, `JSR-275` support in [tag:jscience] can "enforce compile-time check of parameters."